# Send a text from 8051 using TR800

Tags: 8051

I need some help in writing a code which will enable the 8051 to send a text sms using a GSM modem TR800 to any number. I have no clue as where to start. I have tried the following:

```
#include <reg51.h>
void SerTx(unsigned char);
void main(void){
int i =0;
TMOD=0x20; //use Timer 1, mode 2
TH1=0xFD; //9600 baud rate
SCON=0x50;
TR1=1; //start timer
while (i<2) {
SerTx('A');
    SerTx('T');
    SerTx('\\');
    SerTx('r');
    i+=1;
}
}
void SerTx(unsigned char x){
SBUF=x; //place value in buffer
while (TI==0); //wait until transmitted
TI=0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to send an AT command, followed by a carriage return (CR). But you have coded the escape sequence for CR incorrectly. You should send 'A', 'T', and '\r'. The C compiler must see the backslash and the "r" side-by-side to make the conversion to CR. Your code sends literally "AT\r" to the module, which is incorrect.

Once that's working right, you'll need to write some code to accept the reply from the GSM module.